# Symfony2: Join for find() results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Doctrine with Symfony and want to rewrite an old app of mine. For one view I need everything from one table, where I'd nomally use find(). But I also have to access anoter value via join.

Is it possible, to combine the Query Builder with the find() method?

This is my current Action:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
$rep = $em->getRepository('PaulInkBundle:Artist');
$artist = $rep->find($id);
$styles = $rep->getStyles($id);
return $this->render('PaulInkBundle:Artist:artist.html.twig', array(
    'artist'    => $artist,
    'styles'    => $styles
));
```

The getStyles() method fetches the Styles linked to the artist:

```
public function getStyles($id)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT s.name 
                 FROM PaulInkBundle:Style s 
                 WHERE s.id IN (
                        SELECT st.style 
                        FROM PaulInkBundle:ArtistStyle st 
                       WHERE st.artist = :id ) '
           )->setParameter('id',$id)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Would it be possible to do this in one function and thus having the styles within the artist tat is passed to the view?

Edit:

The associations:

Artist(nr) -> ArtistStyle(artist.nr/style.nr) <- Style (nr,name)

Thus, I want to get all Style-names with a specif artist ID

```
class Artist
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
}

class ArtistStyle
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artist", type="integer")
     */
    private $artist;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="style", type="integer")
     */
    private $style;
}

class Style
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descr", type="text")
     */
    private $descr;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your entity's associations(PaulInkBundle:Style, PaulInkBundle:ArtistStyle) ?

Comment: @PeterPopelyskho added (poorly, bc I'm on the train w/ phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have following:

**MANY TO MANY** Association mapping with 
*Artist* and *Style*

So instead of writing this:

```
$artist = $rep->find($id);
$styles = $rep->getStyles($id);
```

You could create one method like this:

```
/**
* @var int $id
* @return Artist|null
*/
public function getArtistWithStyles($id)
{
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
       ->join('a.styles', 's')
       ->where('a.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $id)
       ->getQuery()
       ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

now you can do next:

*Inside your controller:*

```
$artist = $repository->getArtistWithStyles($id);

return $this->render('PaulInkBundle:Artist:artist.html.twig', array(
    'artist'    => $artist,
));
```

*In your view you can access your styles in simple way:*

```
{% for style in profile.getStyles() %}
   {{ style.getName() }}
{% endfor %}
```

Another solution might be next:

You could add [Doctrine extensions bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and use GROUP_CONCAT function. Add it to your doctrine config.

```
dql:
    string_functions:
        group_concat: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
```

and change your getArtistWithStyles method to this:

```
public function getArtistWithStyles($id)
{
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
       ->select('a, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR \'; \')')
       ->join('a.styles', 's')
       ->where('a.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $id)
       ->getQuery()
       ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

you'll get the result like this:

```
[
  'artist' => {Object},
  'styles' => 'style1; style2; style3'
]
```

Comment: WHERE a.id': Error: Class Paul\InkBundle\Entity\Artist has no association named style
Any idea?

Comment: @TechTreeDev show your `entity` code, you probably need to add $styles as many to many relation

Comment: Added, I'm kinda new to Doctrine^^

Comment: @TechTreeDev this is really big subject, [start here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) you probably need many to many association.